# Load table on SSIS with CSV files

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, ssis

I want to load a table from a CSV file, I have a `varchar` field type on the CSV but on my target table it is `integer`.

I want to load with SSIS.

How should I proceed?

Comment: did you get any error when loading the file? the conversion will be done to your source columns

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Data Conversion Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/data-conversion-transformation) on your Dataflow. And change your column from DT_STR to DT_I4.

Comment: Should be the other was round: Change `DT_STR` to `DT_I4`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply specify the column of your CSV source to be `DT_I4` on the *Advanced* tab of your source.

You may want to add an error output for invalid data where this columns contains values that cannot be converted.

Comment: There's no need to change the source CVS file - it's text no matter what you specify in the SSIS source. This means just instructing SSIS to *try to read it as an integer value* - which of course can fail if there's a character value in that columns for some records.